# rails: keep it DRY, to what level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, dry

We always read people saying "keeps things dry" with rails. But to what level?

For example, we have 3 models `Project`, `Offer`, `Revision`. This 3 models can have many `Attachment`.

On the "models" side it is quite straight forward we end up with

```
/app/models/project.rb
/app/models/offer.rb
/app/models/revision.rb
```

But for the controllers side I have problems keeping it DRY. I end up with at least:

```
GET  /projects/:id/attachments    ->   Projects/Attachments#index
POST /projects/:id/attachments    ->   Projects/Attachments#create
GET  /offers/:id/attachments      ->   Offers/Attachments#index
POST /offers/:id/attachments      ->   Offers/Attachments#create
GET  /revisions/:id/attachments   ->   Revisions/Attachments#index
POST /revisions/:id/attachments   ->   Revisions/Attachments#create
```

So basically, I've almost the same code in this 3 locations:

```
controllers/projects/attachments_controller.rb
controllers/offers/attachments_controller.rb
controllers/revisions/attachments_controller.rb
```

My question, should I DRY it up and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRY or "don't repeat yourself" is a general rule of thumb.

in case you find a pattern in your code that repeats itself in several places it might be worth looking into it.

if it's possible to extract a common functionality into, say a module, then you should probably do that.

if you think it's not worth your time, to complex or whatever reason there is not to do it, that is totally fine.

KISS (keeping things simple and stupid) > DRY

make sure your code is simple to follow and refactor and DRY out afterwards.